# Pythong gradient descent linear regression not calculating well

Tags: python, machine-learning, gradient-descent

I've started learning ML following Andrew NG course on coursera. I'm trying to implement the `gradient descent with linear regression` but I'm not sure what am I missing. According to this
[image]

I've tried to implement it but something is wrong. Here is the code. Worth pointing out that this is the first time I'm touching python, without learning the basics.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.ion()

x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [1,2,3,4,5]

def Gradient_Descent(x, y, learning_rate, iterations):
  theta_1=np.random.randint(low=2, high=5); 
  theta_0=np.random.randint(low=2, high=5);
  m = x.shape[0]

def mean_error(a, b, factor):
  sum_mean = 0
  for i in range(m):
    sum_mean += (theta_0 + theta_1 * a[i]) - b[i]  # h(x) = (theta0 + theta1 * x) - y 
    if factor:
      sum_mean *= a[i]
  return sum_mean

def perform_cal(theta_0, theta_1, m):
  temp_0 = theta_0 - learning_rate * ((1 / m) * mean_error(x, y, False))
  temp_1 = theta_1 - learning_rate * ((1 / m) * mean_error(x, y, True))
  return temp_0 , temp_1

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

for i in range(iterations):
    theta_0, theta_1 = perform_cal(theta_0, theta_1, m)
    ax.clear()
    ax.plot(x, y, linestyle='None', marker='o')
    ax.plot(x, theta_0 + theta_1*x)
    fig.canvas.draw()


x = np.array(x)
y = np.array(y)
Gradient_Descent(x,y, 0.1, 500)

input("Press enter to close program")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.ion()

x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [1,2,3,4,5]

def Gradient_Descent(x, y, learning_rate, iterations):
  theta_1=0
  theta_0=0
  m = x.shape[0]
  for i in range(iterations):
      theta_0, theta_1 = perform_cal(theta_0, theta_1, m, learning_rate)
      ax.clear()
      ax.plot(x, y, linestyle='None', marker='o')
      ax.plot(x, theta_0 + theta_1*x)
      fig.canvas.draw()

def mean_error(a, b, factor, m, theta_0, theta_1):
  sum_mean = 0
  for i in range(m):
    sum_mean += (theta_0 + theta_1 * a[i]) - b[i]  # h(x) = (theta0 + theta1 * x) - y 
    if factor:
      sum_mean *= a[i]
  print(sum_mean)
  return sum_mean

def perform_cal(theta_0, theta_1, m, learning_rate):
  temp_0 = theta_0 - learning_rate * ((1 / m) * mean_error(x, y, False, m, theta_0, theta_1))
  temp_1 = theta_1 - learning_rate * ((1 / m) * mean_error(x, y, True, m, theta_0, theta_1))
  return temp_0 , temp_1

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)




x = np.array(x)
y = np.array(y)
Gradient_Descent(x,y, 0.01, 100)
```

Made some changes in your code (mostly rearrange few lines and didn't change anything that you did, so that it doesn't seem confusing), and it's now working. I would suggest you learn the basics of the language first as most of the mistakes were pretty basic such as parameter passing etc. However, It's commendable you're trying stuff on your own by implementing along Andrew Ng's course.

Comment: Thanks! Arguments were fine, realized that the problem is how I've copied the code and I've wasted your time to refactor. `mean_error` and `perform_cal` are local functions inside `Gradient_Descent`. The problem was the initial values of `theta_0` and `theta_1` and also the learning rate. Changing them like in your code everything works!

Comment: Great! As one would say they (learning rate, weight initialization, hyperparameter tuning in general) are the most important part while training any ML model, as they decide whether the model is gonna converge in any feasible time (or converge at all)... so good luck!

Comment: Last thing, as I can see you are good at ML. I cannot seem to find a way/formula to predict a value, not part of the dataset. My assumption would be (if we take my code) to keep the latest `theta_0` and `theta_1` and simply use the hypothesis function to return predicted value. In that case `theta_0 + theta_1 * XToPredict`, is that enough?

Comment: Yeah, your assumption is correct. The purpose of our optimization algorithm (`gradient descent` in your case) is to find the best set of parameters (`theta_0` and `theta_1` in your case) that produces the least cost (`MSE` in your case). So as you've said, you just need to take those optimized parameters after training is done and use the equation of a line (`theta_0 + theta_1 * XToPredict`) to produce the prediction.

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot.